# Bootstrap popover weird behavior with 3.3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need Bootstrap popover in my sub-menu navigation. It's working correctly when I open the menu, there is also a close button for the popover but when opening it again it does not work. This means its working with odd clicks, with even clicks it does not work.

But in Bootstrap 3.3.2 its all working properly

```js
js 

    $(function () {          
       var popOverSettings = {
        placement: 'bottom',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        selector: '#change-customer',
     title: '<a href="#" class="close" >&times;</a>',
        content: function () {
            return $('#customer-popover').html();
        }
    }
    $('body').popover(popOverSettings).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
            enableTypeAhead();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close" , function(){
            $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li id="change-customer"><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
                    <li id="ex2"><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                    <li id="ex3"><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                    <li id="ex5"><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
<div class="col-md-8" id="customer-popover" style="display: none">

    <input class="typeahead form-control inputbox-shadow" type="text" placeholder="Search Customer">
</div>
```

Working Version : [Codeply link](http://www.codeply.com/go/KX7iDAfh4X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroy the popover rather than hiding it:

```
$(this).parents(".popover").popover('destroy');
```